# How to use variable inside my Ajax request function in laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5

I don't know what is going wrong with laravel controller? I want to increment the value of my counter but it is not working.

Code:

```
public function index(Request $request)

{
  $data=0;

  if($request->ajax())
  {
    $data=$data+1;

    //My Code
  }

  return view('home', compact('data'));

}
```

result:

> Data value : 0

Comment: Probably `$request->ajax()` is false. Try to put a debug log inside the loop and check the logs if it is there. Something like: `\Log::debug("Ajax request");`. Then check the logs in `storage\logs\laravel.log`.

Comment: I am using dataTable in Ajax request and that is working fine but counter is not working

Comment: I think ajax function is loding after return view

Comment: yes you are right and thank you Laerte and Alok Mishra